# using case statement how to get count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this:

```
 select ItemCode,ItemDescription,
  CASE
    WHEN dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Status = 1 AND
      dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Site_Code <> dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Frm_Site_Code THEN SUM(dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Quantity)
    ELSE 0
  END,
  CASE
    WHEN dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Status = 2 AND
      dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Site_Code <> dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Frm_Site_Code THEN SUM(dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Quantity)
    ELSE 0
  END
   from T_Item_Movement where F_Site_Code='12004'
   group by ItemCode,ItemDescription,T_Item_Movement.F_Status,T_Item_Movement.F_Site_Code,T_Item_Movement.F_Frm_Site_Code
```

my out put like this:

```
itemcod       description               nocolumnname   nocolumnname
TT015-BLK   BLACK WOODEN TOP - ROUND    6                0
TT015-BLK   BLACK WOODEN TOP - ROUND    0                 5
```

Instead of this i want to get out put like this:

```
 itemcod       description               nocolumnname   nocolumnname
    TT015-BLK   BLACK WOODEN TOP - ROUND    6            5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.

```
 select itemcode, itemdescription, max(somecol1), max(somecol2)
 from ( 
 select ItemCode,ItemDescription,
  CASE
    WHEN dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Status = 1 AND
      dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Site_Code <> dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Frm_Site_Code THEN SUM(dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Quantity)
    ELSE 0
  END as somecol1,
  CASE
    WHEN dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Status = 2 AND
      dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Site_Code <> dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Frm_Site_Code THEN SUM(dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Quantity)
    ELSE 0
  END as comecol2
   from T_Item_Movement 
   where F_Site_Code='12004'
   group by 
   ItemCode,ItemDescription,T_Item_Movement.F_Status,
   T_Item_Movement.F_Site_Code,T_Item_Movement.F_Frm_Site_Code
   ) t
   group by itemcode, itemdescription
```

Comment: try the modified version

Comment: was missing a comma before. try this

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want the earliest ItemCode when itemdescription's match and you want to sum your cases after evaluating if it meets 1 or 2 status, don't count them.

```
SELECT min(itemCode) as ItemCode
 ,ItemDescription
 ,sum(case when FStatus=1 then 1 else 0 end) as in
 ,sum(case when FStatus=2 then 1 else 0 end) as out
FROM tableName
GROUP BY itemDescription
```